# Улетает RigidBody unity3d C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

В коде внизу при нажатии на объект(ему присвоен тег fishka) объект улетает в сторону. Хотя должен ходить за зажатой мышкой. Причем, если отказаться от rigidbody и просто вместо

```
transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(rot*0.1f,ForceMode.VelocityChange);
```

поставить обычный

```
transform.position = rot;
```

То всё окей, объект следует за зажатой мышкой.

```
private Ray ray;
private RaycastHit hit;
private Vector3 rot = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit) && hit.collider.CompareTag("fishka"))
        {

            rot.z = hit.point.z;
            rot.x = hit.point.x;
            transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(rot*0.1f, ForceMode.VelocityChange);

        }
    }
}
```

соответственно вопрос - как сделать так, чтобы именно rigidbody ходил за зажатой мышкой.

Вот как это выглядит. Сначала двигаем через transform.position, потом через rigidbody. https://youtu.be/cIrfZoRaWk4

Comment: Если я ничего не путаю то у тебя 60+- раз за за секунду (по числу fps)объекту докидывается addforce соответственно на него начинает действовать сила и он улетает, ты постоянно ему addforce делаешь, он суммируется.

Comment: @justyx Но ведь вроде так и должно быть. Только сила должна быть направлена туда, где зажатая мышка, пусть и 60 раз в секунду. А оно улетает вправо и вверх.

Comment: Во-первых с rigidbody надо работать в `FixedUpdate`. Во-вторых, если вам нужно не что-то взрывное/импульсное, тогда попробуйте и использовать `rigidBody.velocity` .....`rb.velocity = rot*0.1f;` примерно как-то так ......  а точнее без `*0.1f`  раз вы его без rigidbidy не используете.... скорее всего и так тоже не нужно будет

Comment: @АлексейШиманский А в принципе только что и попробовал. Вернее, если быть точным, то велосити я первым и сделал. И без 0.1f. Улетает только в путь. 

Это не от того что я задаю для ригидбоди вектор силы вида (180, 0, 180)? Просто у меня такая позиция показывается в мышке. У них случаем не другая система отсчета? 

Вот так оно выглядят координаты(там где надпись point) и для тела который улетает(надписи point нет) во время зажатия мышкой. 

(190.7, 0.0, 308.8)Point
(357.4, 0.5, 466.4)
(190.7, 0.0, 308.8)Point
(383.2, 0.5, 507.3)

Comment: @Dmitrii чёт я пропустил момент..... вам нужно же изменять позицию.... то есть `transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position = rot;` ...... всё ...... только должно быть не `rot.z = hit.point.z;` а `rot.y = hit.point.y;`  как я понимаю. ...... а velocity и addforce это немного другое............ а если используете 2D, то и rigidbody2d вроде должен быть

Comment: Еще можете попробовать [MovePosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html) , то есть `transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().MovePosition(rot);` ..... вот отличие его от `transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position = rot;` не смогу подсказать. возможно и нет

Comment: @АлексейШиманский С MovePosition лучше всего работает, но иногда всё равно проникает друг через друга. Чем лечить - не знаю, Continious Dynamic поставил, Extrapolate, но все равно, один раз из ста - проникают объекты друг через друга. Можно как нибудь, чтобы этот Rigidbody не тащило друг через друга силком, а так, прикладывалось небольшое усилие. Ну как AddForce, но в точности по направлению, как MoveTo.
Cейчас при столкновении предметов друг с другом они дёргаются, пытаясь проникнуть друг в друга. Иногда получается.
https://youtu.be/qZdj9CG7TqI
на 31 секунде виден пробой коллайдера.

Comment: @Dmitrii глядя на видео сложно что-то экстрасенсорное разбудить в себе) Вообще, бывает, в платформерах например, если объект управления (персонаж) бежит и втыкается в стену и сила была большая, что немного вошел внутрь на некую величину (обзовем её дельта), то прилагается обратное усилие, чтоб быстро его вытолкнуть на эту самую дельту. ......но в целом я не понимаю что вы делаете и что хотите делать, вашей идеи в целом, чтоб что-то посоветовать на данный момент)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

для перетаскивания предметов мышкой/тачем есть скрипт в юнити под названием DragRigidbody

очень советую попробовать :)

А то что написано... и должно делать именно то что оно делает, кстати говоря :) Вместо движения за пальцем по координатах ты даешь толчек физическому обьекту(риджит боди)

Comment: Где конкретно есть этот скрипт?

Comment: Где конкретно -- понятия не имею. Клацни на любой обьект на сцене, в инспекторе нажимаешь на "добавить компонент" и пишешь его название в фильтре. Я всегда так добавлял когда нужно было.